# Spring web application giving 404 error tomcat

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404

I wanted to make REST Api using Spring.
I have added Tomcat in Run/Debug Configurations.
Here is my Config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dashkindima.blog.mvc")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reeve?autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&amp&characterEncoding=UTF8");
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("1234");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.dashkindima.blog.mvc.hibernatetest.entity");
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I have also defined WebInitializer class

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MyConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/*"};
    }
}
```

I have tried almost all urls in @RequestMapping like /api , /{app_name}/api but nothing happens.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/blog/api")
public class MyRESTController {

    @Autowired
    private LivingComplexService livingComplexService;

    @GetMapping("/living")
    public List<LivingComplex> showAllLivingComplexes(){
        List<LivingComplex> allComplexes = livingComplexService.getAllComplexes();
        return allComplexes;
    }
}
```

You can be sure that Service will return livingComplexes. So the problem is in Tomcat.

Comment: I guess your application is hosted in a `tomcat` server. The url of your service should looks like this : `http://localhost:port-number/application-name/blog/api/living`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).